# Show multiple images on clicking one image using Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I want to show only one image but while clicking on the image the remaining images should be displayed using lightbox. But the image which is not visible should not consume space in the web page. Again, I don't want the image which is not visible to consume space in the web page. It should be hidden as well as not consuming any space.

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ClassicRoom a').lightBox();
    });
 <div class="ClassicRoom">
    <a href="../Project%20Pics/ClassicRooms/ClassicRoom2.jpg" data-title="My caption" data-lightbox="classicroom">
        <img src="../Project%20Pics/ClassicRooms/ClassicRoom2.jpg" tooltip="Rooms&Suites" data-lightbox="classicroom" />
    </a>
        <a href="../Project%20Pics/ClassicRooms/ClassicRoom1.jpg" data-title="My caption" data-lightbox="classicroom">

    </a>
        <a href="../Project%20Pics/ClassicRooms/ClassicRoom3.jpg" data-title="My caption" data-lightbox="classicroom">

    </a>
        <a href="../Project%20Pics/ClassicRooms/ClassicRoom.jpg" data-title="My caption" data-lightbox="classicroom">

    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provice a fiddle or working example.

Comment: What does 'not consuming any space' mean?

Comment: Sorry guys my fault. The header tag was floating outside the div since it was outside the div. I thought it is inside div and because of lightbox images it has gone outside the div. Since the lightbox images was inside the div so I thought the images are conusming space and therefore the header is floating anywhere. Anyway,thanks for your responses.